# How to convert a wav audio file format (sample width) into 8 bits format?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, wave

I am using a Python gui that records the voice and I need to set the Width format of the wav file into 8 bits. When I run the recording has nothing but noise!

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import pyaudio
import wave
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

class App():
    chunk = 1024
    sample_format = pyaudio.paUInt8
    channels = 2
    fs =44100 

frames = []

def __init__(self, master):
    self.isrecording = False
    myFont = font.Font(weight="bold")
    self.button1 = tk.Button(audio_window, text='Record', command=self.startrecording,
                             height=2, width=20, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
    self.button2 = tk.Button(audio_window, text='stop', command=self.stoprecording,
                             height=2, width=20, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
    self.button1['font'] = myFont
    self.button2['font'] = myFont
    self.button1.place(x=30, y=30)
    self.button2.place(x=280, y=30)

def startrecording(self):
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format, channels=self.channels,
        rate=self.fs, frames_per_buffer=self.chunk, input=True)
    self.isrecording = True

    print('Recording')
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
    t.start()

def stoprecording(self):
    self.isrecording = False
    print('recording complete')

    self.filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Save as",
        filetypes=(("audio file", "*.wav"), ("all files", "*.*")),
        defaultextension=".wav")

    wf = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(self.fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
    
def record(self):
    while self.isrecording:
        data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
        self.frames.append(data)
        print("does it")

audio_window = tk.Tk()
audio_window.title('recorder')
app = App(audio_window)
audio_window.geometry('520x120')
audio_window.mainloop()
```

This is the recording GUI I used. I need the recording to be in 8 bits because I need to encrypt it later.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `tkinter` so you should provide a [mre] that isn't using it. The answer most likely has to do with using the `pyaudio` and `wave` modules.

Comment: first try to do it without `tkinter` and `thread` because they have nothing to do with your problem. And you will have minimal working code which you can show in new question and people may try to run it to resolve problem.

Comment: BTW: can't you use `pyaudio.paInt8` at start ?

Comment: Thanks all.. I am a new user . Any ideas pease about my query?

Comment: @furas I tried but the recording  becomes nothing but noise

Comment: Have you tried unsigned 8 bit Pyaudio.paUInt8?

Comment: @Hendrik  Yes I did .. but no results .. I added the full program in the question

Comment: That program cannot be started. You're passing a parameter to `App`, but it does not accept one. Please provide something minimal that's instantly runnable. Preferably without a UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [soundfile.write()](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#soundfile.write) like this:

```
import librosa  # just to demo, not necessary, as you already have the data
import soundfile

# read some wave file, so that y is the date and sr the sample rate
y, sr = librosa.load('some.wav')

# write to a new wave file with sample rate sr and format 'unsigned 8bit'
soundfile.write('your.wav', y, sr, subtype='PCM_U8')
```

To get available subtypes for a certain format, use:

```
>>> soundfile.available_subtypes('WAV')
{'PCM_16': 'Signed 16 bit PCM', 'PCM_24': 'Signed 24 bit PCM', 'PCM_32': 'Signed 32 bit PCM', 'PCM_U8': 'Unsigned 8 bit PCM', 'FLOAT': '32 bit float', 'DOUBLE': '64 bit float', 'ULAW': 'U-Law', 'ALAW': 'A-Law', 'IMA_ADPCM': 'IMA ADPCM', 'MS_ADPCM': 'Microsoft ADPCM', 'GSM610': 'GSM 6.10', 'G721_32': '32kbs G721 ADPCM'}
```

Comment: Please add the code you use to your original question, so that it is readable.

Comment: Does it dither?

Comment: yes @pipll  I added the program i used in the question

Comment: @bipll AFAIK, Python *soundfile* is based on [libsoundfile](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile), which does not appear to dither. But I may be wrong.